# Loading a database dump into settings.local.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recloned my repo, where previously I had my local database linked via my `settings.local.yml` file. I forgot to make a copy of this file and I cannot remember how the syntax is for linking the database dump with a path of `db/structure.sql`

For now all my local tables in Rails are empty of data, I believe the syntax should be something like this, however obviously this is not working, any tips appreciated.

settings.local.yml

```
  db:
  ???: 'db/structure.sql'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `structure.sql`, first make sure you have this line in your `config/application.rb` file:

```rb
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Then put the `structure.sql` file in the `db` folder (`db/structure.sql`).

To load the structure execute this command:

```
rails db:structure:load
```